# Fiddler and Charles proxy cannot intercept specific android app

Tags: android, fiddler, android-security, charles-proxy, frida

I installed [Nox Player](https://www.bignox.com/) emulator on my Windows PC and used both [Fiddler Classic](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to capture traffic from the emulator. I have installed the certificate of `Fiddler` and `Charles Proxy` too. By using [Frida](https://github.com/frida/frida/releases) I'm able to intercept all the traffic of all apps except one app. When I opened the app it run well without any errors but no single traffic was captured. I modified the `.apk` file by removing the `pin-set` in `network_secufity_config.xml` but no luck. Other apps can be intercepted but not this app. Is there any setup I missed or the app has `extra` protection?

This similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60680857/unable-to-intercept-traffic-of-an-android-app) has almost the same problem

Comment: Are you talking about "Fiddler Everywhere" or "Fiddler Classic"? If there is a certificate or pinning problem with that app you should at least CONNECT request on Fiddler Classic. Don't know how Fiddler Everywhere would react. The app you want to capture - does it use HTTP(S) at all? Games often use UDP based protocols. Try [PCAP Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egorovandreyrm.pcapremote) to capture all the data traffic without TLS interception in Wireshark (if it works in an emulator), just to understand what traffic the app creates.

Answer (score 0):

Either it's not HTTP traffic, or it's not viewable.

If it's not HTTP Traffic, you might need a different tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

If it is HTTPS traffic that the proxy can't decrypt, it might be [PKP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Public_Key_Pinning). To capture it you might want to [produce the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480980/print-stacktrace-using-frida) around [basic connection classes](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection), see who's producing the calls, and find how to decrypt it within frida. If you're using OS level platforms like Magisk, there are ways to always trust the certificates at the [system level](https://github.com/NVISOsecurity/MagiskTrustUserCerts), which might save you a hustle.